# sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm using the same Play! sbt configuration for ages now, but now after moving to a new machine (64 bit, Windows 10) I'm getting:

```
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.trace#trace-sigar-libs;0.1.6.1: not found
```

My config is

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.6")

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"
sbt.version=0.13.5
```

Can't find trace-sigar-libs 0.1.6.1 in any repo.

Already cleaned .ivy2/cache and .sbt.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Try deleting every 'target' folder within your project, then do clean build.

Comment: @Yogendra123 did not help, unfortunately

Comment: That's a sign of bit rotting. Your project apparently uses really old dependencies; the activator is dead and its the artifacts long been gone. Try to upgrade to Play 2.4.x... at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems. I've fixed them by upgrading `sbt-plugin` version.

Alternatively, you could either find repository where this artifact is still available (I couldn't find it) or copy it into your local `~/.ivy2` directory from the old machine if applicable.